# Difference between partitioning and fragmentation

Tags: partitioning, fragmentation, distributed-databases

I'm trying to learn something about distributed databases and I stumbled upon the concepts of fragmentation and partitioning. It seems to me as if both do the same thing and produce similar results (deviding a relation horizontally/vertically/both).

So what's the difference between fragmentation and partitioning?

Comment: What RDBMS are you referring to ?

Comment: No specific one. Im just asking in general.

Comment: I think you mean sharding, not fragmentation?

Comment: no no, i meant partitioning, i've actually never heard of sharding...

Comment: Then please clarify what you mean by fragmentation, because the two concepts you're asking about are completely different, at least using the standard definitions of them.

Comment: The question has been closed so I can't write an answer, but _yes_, they can mean the same thing. Especially in an older, academic context. The books about distributed databases I read in the nineties talked about "fragmentation" for (intentionally) splitting a database in parts, stored in different places. But it seems to me that the term has fallen out of favour, perhaps because it makes people think of fragmented disks and memory, so nowadays the preferred term seems to be "partitioning". (And all the cool kids say "sharding"!)

Answer (score 1):

The terminology depends on the RDBMS. In SQL server: `Partitioning` is a DB feature that can be used to improve performance and/or manageability of your DB.

`Fragmentation` happens when your rows in the data pages are non-contiguous due to insert/delete operations. Your DB performance will decrease if you have high fragmentation of your data.

Answer (score -2):

look here.
Remember partitioning and fragmentation on your local hard disk.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skalierbarkeit#Skalierung_hinsichtlich_Datenbankeintr.C3.A4ge_-_Denormalisierung

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, i think thats not comparable..